# get ordinal value for letter PHP

Tags: php

I've been given a datafile where the original creator used alphabetical rather than numeric values to show order.

For example, if there's ten items, they'd be named:

```
12342313A
12342313B
12342313C
12342313D
12342313E
...
```

I need to import these values into a mySQL table that has `order` as a required `int` column, and I need to convert the letter to a number.

Is there a function in PHP to get a numeric value for a letter? Or will I need to do a `substr` to grab the trailing letter, and create an indexed array of letters and just do a lookup against that array?

I'm hesitant to do the simple way above, since I don't know how many objects could potentially exist, and I could need to write an array from A-AAAA or something.

Comment: A note: it doesn't seem that you're looking for the numeric value of a letter (which would be, I suppose, the ASCII representation or the like), but rather the **ordinal** value of a letter. Very distinctly different - if I've got it write, I suggest you re-title your question.

Comment: @Chris-- yes, you're correct. Thanks for the tip

Comment: How high do the letters go? `F`? `Z`? Do they wrap around back to `1` or `A`?

Comment: @webbiedave-- I don't know how high they'll go which is why I don't want to simply hardcode it. I doubt they'll go past Z but I don't know.

Comment: You can't very well convert from one numbering system to another before knowing what system is being used. It may work at first but you could be met with a nasty surprise down the road. Examine the data and find out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) with substr and subtract 64. This will set A to 1, B to 2, etc...

Comment: @Galen-- 
I'm not getting good values using this approach:
`$var = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
foreach ($var as $v){
echo ( ord($v) - 64 );
// result 33 34 35 36 37 38
}`

Comment: thats because youre using lower case letters. The letters in your example were uppercase.  if they are all letters, then use this, if there are letters and numbers then its probably hex and you should use `hexdec`

Answer (score 2):

Try converting it from base 36 to base 10 using base_convert(), I.e. `base_convert($str, 36, 10)`. You might need to strtolower it first, and it'll only work if its not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a simple way to create that array, so you could write a function to figure all that out for you and do something like:

```
    function str_to_num($letters, $max = 'ZZZZZZ') {
        $count = 0;
        for ($i = 'A'; $i < $max; $i++) {
            $count++;
            if ($letters == $i) 
                return $count;
        }
    }
```

Then you could do the substr, find the letters at the end, and then pass it into the function:

```
    str_to_num('A');  // returns 1
    str_to_num('AB'); // returns 28
    str_to_num('AC'); // returns 29
    str_to_num('ABC'); // returns 731
```

Something like that, anyway.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a one-time problem that you've got to correct and won't encounter moving forward, I suggest you use `sort` to... erm, sort out the problem.  Let's say you have all those alpha-numeric order fields in an array, like so:

```
$vals = array (
    '12342313A',
    '12342313D',
    '12342313E',
    '12342313B',
    '12342313C'
);
```

Those are all mixed up, not in order. But, you can call the function `sort` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)) on that array and PHP does a decent job of making sense out of it:

```
    print '<pre>Unsorted: ';
    print_r($vals);
    print '</pre>';

    sort($vals);

    print '<pre>Sorted: ';
    print_r($vals);
    print '</pre>';

/*
Unsorted: Array
(
    [0] => 12342313A
    [1] => 12342313D
    [2] => 12342313E
    [3] => 12342313B
    [4] => 12342313C
)

Sorted: Array
(
    [0] => 12342313A
    [1] => 12342313B
    [2] => 12342313C
    [3] => 12342313D
    [4] => 12342313E
)
*/
```

So far, so good. Now, you've got them ordered, and as a bonus you can use the index of the array as your new field in the database. Alter the table and add a field to hold the new value; we'll call this field `numeric_order`, and in my sample I've called the field that currently holds the alpha-numeric sort data `string_order`.  Loop your sorted array and update the database (for example):

```
foreach ($vals as $x=>$v) {
    $sql = 'UPDATE myTable SET numeric_order = '.($x+1).' WHERE string_order = "'.$v.'"';
}
```

I add 1 to `x` in the loop based on the assumption that you don't want anything to have `0` for the order - if that isn't a concern, then you can just use `x`. This is also predicated on the assumption that no two rows have the same alpha-numeric sort value.

If they do, then all is not lost! Start with your array looking like this:

```
$vals = array (
    3=>'12342313A',
    15=>'12342313D',
    66=>'12342313E',
    101=>'12342313B',
    200=>'12342313C'
);
```

... the numeric keys would represent the unique/primary key of the corresponding row. Instead of `sort`, which does not preserve keys, use `asort` (which *does* preserve keys - [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)), and then your loop looks like this:

```
$ord = 1
foreach ($vals as $x=>$v) {
    $sql = 'UPDATE myTable SET numeric_order = '.$ord.' WHERE id = "'.$x.'"';
    $ord++;
}
```

If my base assumption is wrong, and you'll continue to deal with this method of ordering rows, then in my humble view you ought to re-consider your data design.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have above, it seems like your values (last digit, at least) can be thought as being hex numbers. You can then transform them into decimal numbers through the hexdec function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

Comment: Your comment makes sense. My answer is of course valid only if "values can be thought as being hex numbers". Letters over F would of course invalidate this assumption. ;-)